# How to install and configure Alfresco Community on local computer with Alfresco Office Service (AOS) Configured

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to install Alfresco on local computer with the manual option. So far I have tried the installation on the version 5.2 using the .bin file in ubuntu and the .exe file in Windows, however, the AOS service is not working. After a few literature on the fact, I read that AOS service can only be configured thought SSL configuration and the non-manual installation does not allow that. I am now trying to install the 6.2 version manually and it is not so easy. So far, I have install and configured tomcat, postgresql, alfresco content service and alfresco search service. I am now having problems to start the Alfresco Search service and I suspect that my configuration are not correct. But I still have to configure the AOS service later.

If some one can help me with the complete guide to end up with this deployment, I would be happy.

Actually the error I am getting while stating Sorl with `-f` option is the following:

`ERROR (searcherExecutor-7-thread-1-processing-x:archive) [   x:archive] o.a.s.c.SolrCore null:org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 08180001 Failed to initialize keystore:

Location: ssl.repo.client.keystore

Provider:

Type:     JCEKS
`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you add some specific errors you receive, and/or commands you tried? Thus savy people might understand what the actual issue might be.

Comment: Thank you @Markus-Hermann. I have tried to add the current error I am receiving. So sorry for been late in replying.